# Existe um padrão de nomenclatura para nomes dos índices das tabelas no Mysql?

Tags: mysql, laravel, índices

Parece simples essa pergunta, mas queria saber como definir um padrão. Normalmente utilizando o **Mysql Workbench** é definido um padrão automaticamente, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
fk_tabela1_tabela2_idx
```

Obs: Estou utilizando o Laravel que tem padrões de nomenclatura para tabelas, mas não consegui encontrar nada sobre índices.

Comment: Se está querendo fazer isso no `Laravel` no `migration`?

Comment: Trabalho direto no banco de dados, não estou utilizando **migration** nesse projeto em questão.

Comment: Carlos no Workbench eu consigo escrever um para campos indices! ele tem esse recurso.

Comment: Você utiliza alguma convenção para definir seus índices?

Comment: Eu geralmente para indices coloco do jeito que você fez na descrição da pergunta, mas, não existe padrão a seguir e se existe eu realmente desconheço. Talvez tenha alguém de DBA para dizer algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exemplificar, digamos que você tenha uma tabela `posts` que tem como chave estrangeira o id de um usuário no campo `user_id`. A sua chave estrangeira seria:

```
posts_user_id_foreign // [table]_[columns]_[indextype]
```

Você pode encontrar mais sobre isso na classe `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` [nesse link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1012-L1017), procure pelo método `foreign()`, na linha 395.

Comment: caso tenha resolvido seu problema, não esquece de marcar como solução.